# EaselJS - container mouse events handling

Tags: javascript, createjs, easeljs

I have a container that contains multiple elements. I want to be able to detect clicks on container's children and container's area (rectangle defined by me).

Whenever I define a `hitArea` at the container, its children no more receive mouse events - they are dispatched to the container instead. However without `hitArea` I can't detect a click at the container area.

Fiddles that illustrate the issue:

- [hitArea](http://jsfiddle.net/rs462n76/1/)
- [without hitArea](http://jsfiddle.net/rs462n76/2/)

The only [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/rs462n76/4/) I came up to is to use `hitArea` and on each event verify that there is no child at container to which it may be sent. However this approach is very irritating: I would have to catch all types of mouse events, despite my interest in them at the container level.

Is there an easy solution for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to use another workaround - I created a `DisplayObject`, specified `hitArea` for it, and added it as a first child to the `Container`, the drawback is that I have to define event handlers both at that hitArea-object and Container. But it requires much less work than other solutions I've found.

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rs462n76/5/).

Comment: Using a sub-child for the rest of the hitArea is definitely the right approach -- but you can just listen on `container`, and inspect the `event.target` to determine what was hit, rather than having multiple event listeners. `if (event.target == circle) { doSomething(); }`

Comment: @Lanny, thanks for your response, but I've checked it and it doesn't work, am I missing something: http://jsfiddle.net/rs462n76/7/?

Comment: If you set a hitArea, mousechildren are ignored (this is be design). Using your second approach (another child that is the size you need), you can check the target to see what was clicked. Some minor edits to your fiddle, with comments inline. http://jsfiddle.net/rs462n76/8/